# Wpf Document viewer

Tags: wpf, image, printing, documentviewer

In my WPF application (.Net 4.0, Win7), I'm using Fixed Document and Document viewer to allow user to print and view the document.

This Document displays both images and text and in the document viewer every thing looks fine.

But when the same document is printed on the paper the printed images are looking bit dark and this is not acceptable.

I can export the same document to PDF, and the quality looks same as in the document viewer.

But when this pdf document is printed, the same issue (Images printing dark) can be seen.

We have similar applicaiton where the documents (Contains similar images and text as previous) are designed through Dev Express and looks like Dev Express takes care of printing.

When these DEV Express documents are printed i cant see the black image issue. The images are looking fine.

But when these documents are exported to pdf and print though windows the same dark image problem is seen again.

Is it possible to adjust printer settings to print images as they look in the screen?

Dev Express do any optimizations before printing?

Comment: what happens when you print the images outside of the application?, e.g. if you have the image as a JPG file and then print it from something like MS paint

Comment: I have taken a screen shot of the application and printed the same. Still looks almost same but image is sharpened a bit. Even if i print from pdf the issue remains same.